# Not getting the proper output with re.findall

Tags: python, regex, csv, findall

I'm trying to write a code that reads my input csv file with pandas (df_input) and then uses re.findall for any occurrence of the variables in a list. This list is imported from another .csv file where column[0] (df_expression) contains the variables I want the code to search for and column[1] (df_translation) contains the values I want code to return when there's an exact match. This way, when I search for colors like 'burgundy' and 'maroon' it get's translated to 'red'. I've been trying this setup so I can make changes in my expressions translations without having to change the code itself.

```
df_name = df_input[0]

def expression(expr, string):
    return True if len(re.findall(r'\b' + expr + r'\b', string, re.I)) > 0 else False

resultlist = []
    for lineIndex in range(0, len(df_input)):
        matches_list = []
        for expIndex in range(0, len(df_expressions)):
            if expression(str(df_expressions.ix[expIndex]), str(df_name.ix[lineIndex])):
                matches_list.append(df_translation.ix[expIndex])

df_input['Color'] = resultlist
```

These are the return values:

```
resultlist
[['Black'], ['White'], ['Blue'], ['Red', 'Black'], ['Pink'], .....
```

Current output as found in my output.csv after df_input.to_csv(filepath+filename):

```
Name,Color
a black car,['Black']
a white paper,['White'] 
the sky is blue,['Blue']
this product is burgundy and black,['Red, Black']
just pink,['Pink']
```

Preferred output.csv:

```
Name,Color
a black car,Black
a white paper,White 
the sky is blue,Blue
this product is burgundy and black,Red;Black
just pink,Pink
```

Is it possible to lose the brackets and quotes so whenever I do df_input.to_csv(filepath+filename) I get a clean output?
I've tried df.replace() - doesn't work, neither does adding [0] at the end of my re.findall and a bunch of other stuff. Only thing that seems to do the job is to str(resultlist).replace(), but then the index-match combination is pretty messed up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post runnable code. Not just snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following changes and see how it behaves.

Replace

```
df_input['Color'] = resultless
```

With

```
df_input['Color'] = [', '.join(c) for c in resultlist]
```

This should transform resultless into `['Black', 'White', 'Blue', 'Red, Black', 'Pink', ...]`